# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm Learning Webapi so I'm trying to build a simple Api connected to SQL server and I got this error when I add new Movie data

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Movies_SuperHeroes_HeroId". The conflict occurred in database "SupersDb", table "dbo.SuperHeroes", column 'HeroId'.

I have two models :

Superhero Model:

```
namespace SuperHeroesApi.Models
{
    public class SuperHero
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int HeroId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; } 

       
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; } 

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string City { get; set; } 










    }
}
```

Movie Model :

```
 namespace SuperHeroesApi.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MovieId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }

        public double Rate { get; set; }

        public byte [] Poster { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SuperHero")]
        public int HeroId { get; set; }
       

        //public string  SuuperHeroName { get; set; }

        public virtual SuperHero SuperHero { get; set; }





    }
}
```

dto :

```
namespace SuperHeroesApi.Otds
{
    public class MoviesDtos
    {

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }

        public double Rate { get; set; }

        public IFormFile Poster { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("SuperHero")]
        public int HeroId { get; set; }



    }
}
```

MoviesController:

```
using SuperHeroesApi.Otds;

namespace SuperHeroesApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

        private new List<string> _allowedExtention = new List<string> { "jbg", "png" };
        private long _maxAllowedPosterSize = 5242880;

        public MoviesController(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult>GetAllAsync()
        {
            var movie = await _dbContext.Movies.ToListAsync();

            return Ok(movie);

        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task <IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromForm] MoviesDtos dto)
        {
            if (_allowedExtention.Contains(Path.GetExtension(dto.Poster.FileName).ToLower()))
                return BadRequest();

            using var dataStream = new MemoryStream();
            await dto.Poster.CopyToAsync(dataStream);


            var movie = new Movie
            {
                Title = dto.Title,
                Year = dto.Year,
                Rate = dto.Rate,


                Poster = dataStream.ToArray(),
            };

              await _dbContext.AddAsync(movie);
              _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(movie);
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: you are referencing superhero in movies, when you then create a new movie, you don't set the heroid.

Comment: @gsharp hi, do you mean in the movie model or the dot?
can you explain more please

Answer (score 7):

You probably already have existing rows before you made changes to your schema. Now that you're creating a new foreignkey `HeroId` in movie which cannot be null and an integer for that matter which means it will be a zero by default. It becomes a problem for the existing rows because they will try to reference a Hero entity with Id of 0 which doesn't exist. So, the obvious solution is to make the foreign key nullable and redo the migrations

```
[ForeignKey("SuperHero")] 
public int? HeroId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm curious. You had this answer marked as accepted, then you removed it later. did it not solve your problem?

Comment: your answer guided me to a better way to solve my problem and to implement my app better than the way I have planned, so thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not giving Id by yourself ,it will automatically generate it .
if your class look like this

```
public class Canditate:Entity,IHasCreationTime
    {
        [Required]
        public String Name { get;set; } 

        public String Position { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set ; }

        public Canditate()
        {
            CreationTime = DateTime.Now;    
        }
    }
```